# When I replace my rating with season rating will both rating raplaced? (solo + party)

Tags: dota-2

I want ask if some of you played 40+ ranked games in battlepass season and when you after season changed your rating for season-rating if it is change both ratings solo and party, or you could choose?
My rating is 3.300+- solo and 3.900+- party, and my season-rating is 3700+-solo, and 3.200+- party, so after season when I will replace my rating for season rating, I should have 3700+- solo and 3900+- party?
Thanks

Comment: Yes that's how it will be. You can choose whether or not you want to replace your current mmr with season mmr separately for both solo and party.

Comment: @Auditore Could you post that as an answer so I can vote it up? If you have a source to link, even better!

Comment: @Anko I am not quite sure about this that's why I posted it as a comment :D

Comment: Can I raplace my party mmr when I still didnt played 10 rating-party calibration games? but I already played 40+ solo?